# Shell title not showing in xamarin forms android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The title on my shell xaml page is not showing, this is my code:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoanApp2.Views"
             xmlns:bindingVM="clr-namespace:LoanApp2.ViewModel"
             xmlns:contentView="clr-namespace:LoanApp2.ContentViews"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Title="Hehehe"
             x:Class="LoanApp2.MainPage" BackgroundColor="#62bef0" >
```

As you can see the title is already declared but it doesn't show. I've also tried:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Label Text="Hehe"/>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

But it still doesn't work. The shell page is called by a previous screen with the code `Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();`

Comment: It seems that `Shell.Title` doesn't do anything. The title on NavigationBar will show you the title of your current page.So you need set the title in your current page.

Comment: Even FlyoutItem is not showing title in fact title is not shown at any case. even on latest pre1 5.0.0 of XF. wow this questionhas been asked 4 months  ago